# "\b" not working when writing into a text file using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a backspace character, "\b", into a text file using python.
This is my code:

```
with open("newFile.py", "w") as file:
    file.write("Should \bbe \bno \bspace")
```

However, it does not perform the backspace, instead it writes a strange character:
[Strange Character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGykJ.png)

I expected to output something like

```
Shouldbenospace
```

How can I fix this?
I am using PyCharm btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Printing the `\b` does not literally "unwrite" the previous character, it just writes a [control character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) which your terminal may interpret as [moving the cursor back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace#%5EH), so that the subsequent character overprints it. If you render the file to terminal with e.g. [`less`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)) or similar you should see output which *looks* like:

```
Shouldbenospace
```

PyCharm displays the "strange characters" in the UI so that you know they are actually there.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense. I guess I'm going to have to write code to get around this.